# Laravel: Include javascript code via min.js file "Uncaught ReferenceError: HelloWeek is not defined"

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, laravel-5

I would like to include the great "helloweek" javascript code into my Laravel project. To add this, I've taken the **helloweek.min.js** file and placed it in the **/public/js** folder of my project. I've done the same thing for the css file (**helloweek.min.css**), it's in the **/public/css** folder.

The files are included as follows:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/helloweek.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{{ asset('js/helloweek.min.js') }}" defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript">        
const myCalendar = new HelloWeek({
    selector: '.hello-week',
    lang: 'en',
    langFolder: '{{ url('/') }}/assets/lang/',
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    weekShort: true,
    monthShort: false,
    multiplePick: false,
    defaultDate: false,
    todayHighlight: true,
    disablePastDays: true,
    disabledDaysOfWeek: false,
    disableDates: false,
    weekStart: 1,
    daysHighlight: false,
    range: false,
    minDate: false,
    maxDate: false,
    nav: ['◀', '▶'],
    onLoad: () => { /** callback function */ },
    onChange: () => { /** callback function */ },
    onSelect: () => { /** callback function */ },
    onClear: () => { /** callback function */ }
});</script>
```

I can access both my files using "http://homestead.test/js/helloweek.min.js" & "http://homestead.test/css/helloweek.min.css" and I see they are included in my webpage as well via the browser console.

But I get the following **error in the console: home:97 Uncaught ReferenceError: HelloWeek is not defined at home:97**

As far as I know, it should mean that it's unable to find the library but (according to my very limited laravel knowledge) it seems correctly included.

Does anyone have a solution for this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: just remove the "defer" in the js ... [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HelloWeek` is not defined because of `defer` in `<script src="{{ asset('js/helloweek.min.js') }}" defer></script>`.

`Defer` makes the script to load later at the end after page finishes parsing.

Since `helloweek.min.js` is still not executed,`HelloWeek` is not defined yet.

Comment: Welcome :) But let me know if there was any special reason of putting that `defer` there?

Comment: Suprise suprise, due to a copy/paste ofcourse :) in the script included by default by laravel, it's "<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>. As I'm new to laravel, I'm not yet confident in messing around. Should have looked up the "defer" keyword...